# Notifications controls of a music player are not showing the correct information

Tags: java, android-notifications, android-music-player

I'm trying to fix the code from an app a friend of mine wrote. What happens is that it doesn't displays the correct track info in the notification controls. For example, where the album name usually goes, it displays the name of the song followed by "(playing now)", where the name of the song goes it shows the name of the app and an empty space where the artist name goes.

I don't know what it's supposed to be the problem, but I think it's in this line: { "_id", "album_art", "album" }. I've tried changing it, putting "song_name", "song_title", adding "artist_name". No matter what I try I get an error saying that the new items don't exist. The section of code is like this:

```
  localObject1 = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
  localObject2 = App.a().getContentResolver();
  Object localObject3 = String.valueOf(d.g());
  localObject2 = ((ContentResolver)localObject2).query((Uri)localObject1, new String[] { "_id", "album_art", "album" }, "album=?", new String[] { localObject3 }, "album_key");
  localObject1 = localBitmap;
  if (localObject2 != null)
```

I don't know what else to do, so if someone can help me I would be forever thankful.